# SQL Cursor Error - Does not currently have a cursor allocated to it

Tags: sql, cursor

I have been attempting to create a cursor that will pass multiple variables and then eventually the select that is within the cursor will eventually become an update. But for my preliminary stages It will just be a select.

However when i am running this i am receiving an error message multiple times.
 "The variable '@Cur' does not currently have a cursor allocated to it"

Please can I have some assistance with the SQL as i am not sure what is going wrong with it? Im sure it is something simple but I am unable to figure this out.

PS. ignore the column numbers and table numbers this was for example purposes.

```
       DECLARE
            @VAL1 DATETIME,
            @VAL2 INT,
            @VAL3 INT

        SELECT * INTO #TEMP1 FROM
            (SELECT 
                    BS.COL,
                    BS.COL,
                    BS.COL
                FROM TABLEB
                    JOIN TABLe1 HO (NOLOCK) ON HO.COL1 = B.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE2 SPB (NOLOCK) ON B.COL2 = SPB.COL2
                    JOIN TABLE3 BS (NOLOCK) ON BS.COL1 = SPB.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE4 SPS (NOLOCK) ON SPS.COL1 = BS.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE5 P (NOLOCK) ON P.COL1 = BS.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE6 (NOLOCK) ON PS.COL1 = SPS.COL1
                WHERE BS.col1 = 'N'
                    AND SPB.COL1  = 'N'
                    AND SPS.COL2 = 'N'
                    AND PS.COL3 = 'N'
                    AND P.COL4 = 'N'
                    AND B.COL5 = 'N'
                    AND BS.COL5 IS NULL 
                    AND PS.COL6 IS NOT NULL
                    AND PS.COL6 IS NULL
                    AND PS.COL7 <= DATEADD(DAY,-10,GETDATE())
                    AND BS.COL8 IS NOT NULL) Y

        DECLARE @Cur CURSOR SELECT
                    CASE WHEN 
                        BS.COL1 IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN ISNULL((SELECT COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL2 IN (SELECT COL1 FROM #TEMP1)),PS.COL2)
                    WHEN PS.COL2 <> SPS.COL3 THEN SPS.COL5
                    ELSE PS.COL3 END AS 'DATE',
                BS.COL3,
                BS.COL2
            FROM TABLEB
                    JOIN TABLE1 HO (NOLOCK) ON HO.COL1 = B.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE2 SPB (NOLOCK) ON B.COL2 = SPB.COL2
                    JOIN TABLE3 BS (NOLOCK) ON BS.COL1 = SPB.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE4 SPS (NOLOCK) ON SPS.COL1 = BS.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE5 P (NOLOCK) ON P.COL1 = BS.COL1
                    JOIN TABLE6 (NOLOCK) ON PS.COL1 = SPS.COL1
                WHERE BS.col1 = 'N'
                    AND SPB.COL1  = 'N'
                    AND SPS.COL2 = 'N'
                    AND PS.COL3 = 'N'
                    AND P.COL4 = 'N'
                    AND B.COL5 = 'N'
                    AND BS.COL5 IS NULL 
                    AND PS.COL6 IS NOT NULL
                    AND PS.COL6 IS NULL
                    AND PS.COL7 <= DATEADD(DAY,-10,GETDATE())
                    AND BS.COL8 IS NOT NULL
                AND PS.COL 3 <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP


        OPEN @Cur
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @Cur INTO @VAL1 ,@VAL2,@VAL3
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS  = 0
            BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = @VAL2
        FETCH NEXT FROM @Cur INTO @VAL1,@VAL2,@VAL3
        END
        CLOSE @Cur
        DEALLOCATE @Cur
        DROP TABLE #TEMP1
```

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (This doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: Is this the actual script you're using?  No DBMS I'm aware of will allow for unquoted spaces in table and variable names...

Comment: why do you create a temp table if you never read it ( not to mention, that you drop it twice)?

Comment: Hi All, Apologies about the Drop twice - That shouldnt be in there, must have gotten in when  editing it. I do read from this, but during removing the table names it must have lost it's sense a little. Please try to avoid getting caught up on column and table names, these are not the actual name of these as they had to be removed.

Comment: why on earth are you doing this in a cursor? Row by row operations are not a good choice for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the FOR in "DECLARE @Cur CURSOR SELECT" . Change this to "DECLARE @Cur CURSOR FOR SELECT"

Comment: Hi Adish, Many thanks for your help :). I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case because of condition mismatch following statement was not getting fired hence the exception was thrown.

```
SET @Cur=CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
```